# Use POST method from Wordpress page to Google Apps Script

Tags: wordpress, post

I wonder how it could be possible to use POST request from a Wordpress page to Google Apps Script and getting information back.

Is it possible? How?
Found just a few literature about that not enough to complete anything.

Thanks for your help!

akaii

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [Apps Scripts Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Make sure that on the implementation of the `doPost(e)` method, you either return a `HtmlOutput` or a `TextOutput` object. More information [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content).

Once the Web App is deployed you can make a POST HTTP call from your Wordpress application.

Comment: hi Gustavo 
And thanks!
The Google Apps Scripts Web Apps is ok for me, it's more about how to request it from Wordpress that I'm not really aware.

Comment: Hi @akaii, in that case, I'd recommend reviewing the tags applied to your question. You can refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for more info.